# Scanning letters and floats using the java scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a string which looks like this:

"m 535.71429,742.3622 55.71428,157.14286 c 0,0 165.71429,-117.14286 -55.71428,-157.14286 z"

and i want the java scanner to ouput the following strings: "m", "535.71429", "742.3622", "55.71428", "157.14286", "c", ...

so everything seperated by a comma or a space, but I am having troubles getting it to work.

This is how my code looks like:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(path_string);
scanner.useDelimiter(",||//s");
String s = scanner.next();
if (s.equals("m")){ 
    s = scanner.next();
    point[0] = Float.parseFloat(s);
    s = scanner.next();
    point[1] = Float.parseFloat(s);
    ....
```

but the strings that come out are: "m", " ", "5", "3", ...

Comment: What is point[0], point[1]? Is that the place where you are trying to store the output?

Comment: yes, i want to save the float values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think trouble is with //s. You have to use this pattern:

```
scanner.useDelimiter("(,|\\s)");
```

Regex patterns:

```
abc…    Letters
123…    Digits
\d      Any Digit
\D      Any Non-digit character
.       Any Character
\.      Period
[abc]   Only a, b, or c
[^abc]  Not a, b, nor c
[a-z]   Characters a to z
[0-9]   Numbers 0 to 9
\w      Any Alphanumeric character
\W      Any Non-alphanumeric character
{m}     m Repetitions
{m,n}   m to n Repetitions
*       Zero or more repetitions
+       One or more repetitions
?       Optional character
\s      Any Whitespace
\S      Any Non-whitespace character
^…$     Starts and ends
(…)     Capture Group
(a(bc)) Capture Sub-group
(.*)    Capture all
(ab|cd) Matches ab or cd
```

We use dual `\` because this is special symbol and `|` isn't

Comment: Thank you very much! What is the difference betweeen | and ||?

Comment: @MoritzBurgi accept answer please if it's helped you

Comment: `||` doesn't have a special meaning in a regular expression. I think the regular expression `(a||b)` Seeks for an `a`, a `b` and an emtpy string (the void between the first `|` and the second `|`). [regex101](https://regex101.com/) warns with the following message: *"An alternator at this position effectively truncates the group, rendering any other tokens beyond this point useless"*.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output to be strings, the `Float.parseFloat(s);` is of no use for your problem. Is your array a float-array?

Because if it is, your should not get any output but an `NumberFormatException`, because the string "m" cannot be parsed into a float.

Furthermore, to solve the problem of the single values, you could use a [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) which constructs your numbers and ignores the letters and commas. A special use of the letters should be implemented.

Finally, if it is not absolutely neccessary, use double instead of float. It's just so much safer and might save your from some more problems within you program!

Comment: I want to parse a SVG-file. I alternetly search for a letter and then save the float values that follow. I think I need to build in a check if the parsed token is a comprised of letters or digits.